# How to determine Voltage-Time Product needed for Push-Pull TX?

Tags: transformer, push-pull

I'm using an LT3999 IC to drive a push-pull TX at 15V. The TX I have has a VT of 10V*us. What is the minimum frequency I need to run it at? I found 2 conflicting formulas.

I have the formula VT = Voltage * time at Voltage.
and: 1/F = time at voltage.

so, 10Vus = 15 * 1 / F
F = 15/ 10Vus = 1.5 Mhz

*But*... I've also seen the formula,
VT = Vmax / (2*F)
which leads to 750Khz.

Which formula is correct?

I can run at 750Khz but 1.5MHz is beyond the ability of the LT3999 and I'll need to get new TXs.

[image]